# Is it possible to adorn a LINE OF CODE with a Conditional Attribute? (or something similar)

Tags: .net, logging, attributes

I plan to put a call to MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod() at the beginning of most methods (for informative logging), but since this would present a high overhead, it would be good if a conditional attribute could be used used like:

```
#define LogMethodNames
```

where...

```
[Conditional("LogMethodNames")]
```

was put above every line call GetCurrentMethod(), like:

```
void DoStuff()
{
    [Conditional("LogMethodNames")]
    logger.CurrentMethod = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();

    //  stuff done here
}
```

...so at least it could be excluded from release builds.

Is something along these lines possible?

Thanks!

Gregg

PS I would try this myself now but for some reason I couldn't get Attributes to work due to a compile error. Doh.

PPS If this can't work I'd create a method which assigns to the logger object, like:

```
void SetCurrentMethod(MethodBase currentMethod)
{
    logger.CurrentMethod = currentMethod;
}
```

and use:

```
void DoStuff()
{
    [Conditional("LogMethodNames")]
    SetCurrentMethod(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());

    //  stuff done here
}
```

Any thoughts?! Thanks  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close - you would need to set the `Conditional` attribute on the method itself:

```
[Conditional("LogMethodNames")]
void SetCurrentMethod(MethodBase currentMethod)
{
    logger.CurrentMethod = currentMethod;
}
```

For more information please see [The Conditional attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664622%28VS.71%29.aspx):

> The attribute Conditional enables the
>   definition of conditional methods. The
>   Conditional attribute indicates a
>   condition by testing a conditional
>   compilation symbol. Calls to a
>   conditional method are either included
>   or omitted depending on whether this
>   symbol is defined at the point of the
>   call. If the symbol is defined, the
>   call is included; otherwise, the call
>   (including evaluation of the
>   parameters of the call) is omitted.